# Nested data with ng-repeat table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm in need of some help creating a table using angularjs  to build my table.  The issue here is my data has multiple nested levels, and my problem is that I cannot get the innermost level to display.  In this example the task record is not shown.  Here is a modified verison of my code which is defined as the templateUrl in my directive.

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
<tr>
    <th>Identifier</th>
    <th ng-click="changeSorting('title')" ng-show="blnShowTitle">Title</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat-start="incident in incidents | orderBy:sort.column:sort.descending | filter:tablefilter ">
    <td>{{incident.identifier}}</td>
    <td ng-show="blnShowTitle">{{incident.title}}</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="ap in incident.action_plans | orderBy:sort.column:sort.descending | filter:tablefilter 
" ng-show="incident.action_plans.length > 0">
    <td>{{ap.identifier}}</td>
    <td ng-show="blnShowTitle">{{ap.title}}</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="task in ap.tasks" ng-show="ap.tasks.length > 0">
    <td>{{task.task_number}}</td>
    <td ng-show="blnShowTitle">{{task.title}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

JSON (sample data):

```
[
 {
    "event_id": "23",
    "event_number": "EVT-00000023",
    "title": "Test%20kc%20ml",
    "action_plans":
    [
      {
        "event_id": "23",
        "action_plan_id": "46",
        "action_plan_number": "AP-00000046",
        "title": "What we do next is this.",
        "tasks":
        [
          {
            "action_plan_id": "46",
            "task_id": "18",
            "task_number": "APT-00000018",
            "title": "ml task name"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "selected": "false"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be what you are looking to do.  You need to nest your ng-repeat-start, as shown below.

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="thing in app.things">
    <td>{{thing.label}}</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat-start="action in thing.actions">
    <td>{{thing.label}}</td>
    <td>{{action.label}}</td>
    <td>&nbsp</td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="task in action.tasks">
    <td>{{thing.label}}</td>
    <td>{{action.label}}</td>
    <td>{{task.label}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat-end></tr></tr>
```

[Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/ts6P1wp4dH7hMPOVCiDb?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks!...this works as expected.  The empty tr at the end was the missing piece.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're trying to do a nested `ng-repeat` that isn't nested, you basically have (simplified):

```
<tr ng-repeat="ap in incident.action_plans"></tr>
<tr ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="task in ap.tasks"></tr>
```

You have to move the `ng-repeat` with `ap.tasks` to be in scope of `ap` - right now it isn't.